# Cómo puedo cambiar el primary color de un framework css?

Tags: css, sass

Tengo entendido que los framework css trabajan sus componentes a través de sass, pero he intentado cambiar el valor de las variables dentro del código sass de la librería pero no ha funcionado, el framework que uso en si no es un framework, sino una modificación de bootstrap, es un kit, pero funciona casi igual

he modificado el archivo de la libreria: variables.scss

específicamente éstas líneas:

```
// Global settings

$enable-caret:              true !default;
$enable-rounded:            true !default;
$enable-shadows:            true !default;
$enable-gradients:          false !default;
$enable-transitions:        true !default;
$enable-grid-classes:       true !default;
$enable-print-styles:       true !default;


// Color system

$white:    #ffffff !default;
$gray-100: #f6f9fc !default;
$gray-200: #e9ecef !default;
$gray-300: #e3e3e3 !default;
$gray-400: #ced4da !default;
$gray-500: #adb5bd !default;
$gray-600: #6c757d !default;   // Line footer color
$gray-700: #525f7f !default;   // Line p color
$gray-800: #32325d !default;   // Line heading color
$gray-900: #212529 !default;
$link-disabled:              #666666 !default;
$transparent-bg:             transparent !default;
$light-bg:                   #f5f6fa !default;
$dark-background:            #555555 !default;


$grays: () !default;
$grays: map-merge((
  "100": $gray-100,
  "200": $gray-200,
  "300": $gray-300,
  "400": $gray-400,
  "500": $gray-500,
  "600": $gray-600,
  "700": $gray-700,
  "800": $gray-800,
  "900": $gray-900
), $grays);

$blue:    #5e72e4 !default;
$indigo:  #5603ad !default;
$purple:  #8965e0 !default;
$pink:    #f3a4b5 !default;
$red:     #f5365c !default;
$orange:  #fb6340 !default;
$yellow:  #ffd600 !default;
$green:   #2dce89 !default;
$teal:    #11cdef !default;
$cyan:    #2bffc6 !default;

$line-height-lg:              1.625rem !default;
$line-height-sm:              1.5 !default;
$line-height:                 1.35em         !default;


$opacity-gray-3:             rgba(222,222,222, .3) !default;
$opacity-gray-5:             rgba(222,222,222, .5) !default;
$opacity-gray-8:             rgba(222,222,222, .8) !default;


$opacity-5:                  rgba(255,255,255, .5) !default;
$opacity-6:                  rgba(255,255,255, .6) !default;
$opacity-8:                  rgba(255,255,255, .8) !default;



$opacity-1:                  rgba(255,255,255, .1) !default;
$opacity-2:                  rgba(255,255,255, .2) !default;


// end beniamin

$colors: () !default;
$colors: map-merge((
  "blue":       $blue,
  "indigo":     $indigo,
  "purple":     $purple,
  "pink":       $pink,
  "red":        $red,
  "orange":     $orange,
  "yellow":     $yellow,
  "green":      $green,
  "teal":       $teal,
  "cyan":       $cyan,
  "white":      $white,
  "gray":       $gray-600,
  "light":      $gray-400,
  "lighter":    $gray-200,
  "gray-dark":  $gray-800
), $colors);

$default-color-opacity:      rgba(182, 182, 182, .6) !default;
$orange-color:               #f96332 !default;

$default:       #344675 !default;
$primary:       blue !default;
$secondary:     #f4f5f7 !default;
$success:       #00f2c3 !default;
$info:          #1d8cf8 !default;
$warning:       #ff8d72 !default;
$danger:        #fd5d93 !default;
$black:         #222a42 !default;
```

El kit se llama BLK Design system

Comment: y si mínimo muestras lo que has intentado en código, añades que framework, no vamos a adivinar

Comment: Ya edité la pregunta, mira y coméntame que opinas

Comment: Necesitas aplicar el cambio a variables.css y refrescar la cache del navegador para apreciar el nuevo color.

Comment: Tienes que compilar el SASS/SCSS para que te genere el nuevo CSS modificado.

Comment: Loa acabé de hacer, no funcionó :/

Comment: @EstebanCalle prueba con ctrl + R o cambia de navegador, probablemente lo que dice Armando tenga razón y el css siga almacenado en memoria caché y obviamente ya debiste de haber vuelto a compilar todo el sass.

Comment: Alvaro tienes razón, había olvidado compilar de nuevo el sass, ahora si funciono, muchas gracias

Comment: Yo recargué el navegador, además lo probé también en incognito, pero no funciono, lo que hice fue probar compilar el sass y funcionó, no sé que pasó que no me funcionaba

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Sass](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sass_(lenguaje_de_hojas_de_estilo)) es un metalenguaje de CSS, es decir, es un lenguaje de script que es traducido a CSS. Del mismo modo que, por ejemplo, los cambios hechos en un código fuente en C no se reflejan en el programa hasta que se compila, los cambios que haces en Sass/SCSS no se reflejan automáticamente en el fichero CSS, sino que deben traducirse primero.

Entonces para solucionar el problema **compila el Sass/SCSS para que genere un nuevo CSS** modificado donde aparezcan tus cambios.

Dependiendo de cómo tengas instalado Sass en tu computadora, tendrás que hacer algo parecido a esto para compilar a CSS:

```
sass entrada.scss salida.css
```